# Which directory to put mocks?

Tags: testing, go, mocking, gomock

I've been most recently experimenting with [`GoMock`](https://github.com/golang/mock), the test mocking framework supported by the official creators of the Go language. I was wondering where is the most reasonable place to put these mocked files.

My current directory structure is as follows. Is this how Go projects should be structured?

```
appname
|-- gateways
    |-- gateway1.go
    |-- gateway1_test.go
    |-- gateway2.go
    |-- gateway2_test.go
    |-- mocks
        |-- gateway1.go
        |-- gateway2.go
```

This is slightly influenced by Ben Johnson's talk [here](https://go-talks.appspot.com/github.com/benbjohnson/structuring-applications-for-growth/main.slide#1).

Answer (score 6):

I tend to follow this article also by Ben Johnson

[Link to article](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1)

In general this approach of having a package for your shared mocks is a good one. One thing worth pointing out here is that if you don't define your models outside of the `gateways` package you could get an import cycle.

1. `gateways` defines models
2. `mocks` imports `gateways.Model`
3. `gateways` imports `mocks` for tests

There are 2 ways to fix this; the first is just to move your models into `domain`, a root package outside `gateways` (see article for examples). Or only test the public interface of your `gateways` package by using `gateways_test` as the package in your test files.

Answer (score 0):

I place it in the same package as my interface and in my opinion it's a good place because it's separated from inherited structs  I think your project structure is not good I rather do below (its base on DDD architecture)

example

```
appname
|-- gateways
    |-- gateway.go //this file contain interface and mocks 
    |-- gateway1
        |-- gateway1.go
        |-- gateway1_test.go 
    |-- gateway2
        |-- gateway2.go
        |-- gateway2_test.go
```